# grouped_collection_select with different option_key_methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations, grouped-collection-select

I'm using `grouped_collection_select` with polymorphic associations to assign either a `company` or `person` to a task.  The issue is that people have a first name and a last name, while a company just has a name.  I would like to use a concatenation of `:fname` and `lname` as the `option_key_method` for the person group in the menu and I would like to use `:name` as the `option_key_method` for the company group in the menu.

I however haven't run across this in my Google investigation.  As it stands, I'm using `:email` as the `option_key_method` because it's the most distinguishing field that's shared by the two models:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :entity_id, [Company, Person], :all, :model_name, :to_global_id, :email %>
```

How might I set it up to make use of the two different kinds of name fields that are implemented by the two different models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a lambda method to the `option_key_method`, which takes the object currently in hand `Person` or `Group` in your case and you can do the processing you want on it

Example:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :entity_id, [Company, Person], :all, :model_name, :to_global_id, lambda {|company_or_person_object| company_or_person_object.instance_of? Company ? company_or_person_object.fname + company_or_person_object.lname : company_or_person_object.name} %>
```

Comment: Great solution.  The lambda method threw a syntax error (it didn't like the colon between the two name types) that I got around using the following: `lambda {|company_or_person_object| company_or_person_object.instance_of? Company? rescue company_or_person_object.fname + " " + company_or_person_object.lname rescue company_or_person_object.name}`

Comment: is it possible to customize collection or group_method? for example instead :all I want to use .where(account_id: id) and instead :model_name I want to use model_name.gsub